# Certificate and private key pair IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I am an iOs developer. In my job we have a mac mini with lion 10.7 and now we need to update it to be able to compile apps to iOs7.

I installed a virtual machine for testing purposes before reinstall lion in mac mini. So I can test xcode 5.I am not able to debug app in job's iphone.

I connect with my account as I did in mac mini but each time I want to run the app in the iphone I get this message:

No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

After, xcode says it can fix it, I click there. Then I get other comment. "You  are not allowed to perform this operation, Only agents and admins are allowed to add devices to this team...

Iphone is already added. I was able to upload programs before update it.

I have email and password of my admin so I can access to add certifies or whatever I need. The problem is that I don't know what I have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fix this by exporting your **Developer Profile** from your Mac Mini, and importing it into your virtual machine. [See here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57059/how-do-i-transfer-my-ios-developer-profile-to-another-computer) for detailed instructions for both Xcode 4 and Xcode 5.

The explanation is this: when you first generated your developer certificate on your mac mini, you sent Apple a certificate signing request. This entailed the creation of a public/private key pair, of which the public part was sent to Apple to be used for encryption and signature verification. The private key remained safely on your mac mini to be used for decrypting and signing purposes.

Now, your virtual machine is sorely missing that private key, and as a consequence all certificates and provisioning profiles you created in your account cannot be decrypted anymore and you virtual machine Xcode cannot sign whatever you would like to send Apple.

The fix is copying over the public/private key pair to your virtual machine.
The post above describes how to entirely transfer your developer profile, but you could also do that from the Mac Keychain by exporting the private key associated to your developer certificates.

As a last note, consider that the developer certificate you can download from Apple Developer website only contains the public portion of the key pair. The private key does only reside in your host.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I exported public and private key but while trying to import private key, virtual machine says: "The contents of this item cannot be retrieved" The public part, is ok imported...

Comment: I imported everything from my other mac, and I get this error while compiling: CodeSign error: no provisioning profile at path '/Users/pablo/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/LONGNUMBER-WITH-SEPARATORS.mobileprovision'

Comment: you mean you exported/imported the private key through keychain? look here, it seems there is a catch: <http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/14751-importing-private-keys-what-is-the-trick.html> (got to first Fontano's reply)

Comment: otherwise, give a try to the export/import of developer profiles from Xcode, this should take care of everything...

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported correctly you developer profile?

If you go in Xcode - Preferences - Accounts you'll can see your apple id, clicking on View Details you can see your associated profiles, refresh your list and then in your building settings you'll be able to choose the right profile